# Set up sftp user with only access to one folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp

I have a folder /home/ubuntu/storage/one

How do I create a user one@myip who can only access that folder, and no SSH access either? Every tutorial I have followed is either outdated or not working

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you considered directions such as found [here](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/sftp-chroot-restrict-user-specific-directory/)? Current for CentOS 8 and was the first hit on my google search.